# Offline lossless image shrinking

Tags: looking-for-a-script, images, compression

I'm looking for something like Smush.it or PunyPNG that works offline, preferably via command line interface that does gifs, jpegs and pngs.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PNGCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) is the first that comes to mind.

[Trimage](http://trimage.org/) is a bit more comprehensive as far as toolset, and has a GUI also.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac there's [ImageOptim](http://imageoptim.com) and [ImageAlpha](http://pngmini.com).